# SQLite get last row ID after connection is closed

Tags: c#, sqlite, lastinsertid

I have two functions.

One Insert into database. It opens the connection and closes it after insert.
Other is GetLastID function.

I know I could query the biggest ID but I was told it's a bad practice.

"SELECT sqlite_last_insert_rowid();" seems no use since I'm closing the connection after Insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence where name=@Table
```

It has solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to insert the data and retrieve the id using the same connection (without closing it).

You would do something similar to the below SQL:

```
string sql = "Insert into Product (Name) values(@Name); SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS ProductID;";
```

then you will have to use the command objects `ExecuteScalar()` function instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` to get the rowid.

Do make sure your table has a column named `ProductID`, typically INTEGER with autoincrement and set as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

last_insert_rowid() (and similar functions in other databases) by their nature only work on the current connection. Can you not refactor your code to query last_insert_rowid() before closing the connection ?

If that's not possible for whatever reason, I guess that only leaves querying the biggest ID. That's regarded as bad practice, because there might have been another row inserted immediately after and so you can't guarantee you'll be getting the ID of the row you think. Is there another column in the database with a unique index that you could query on instead ? That is, something like:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'somone@gmail.com'
```

would be a reliable alternative when email is guaranteed unique.